# PHP Fatal error for getFrontNameByRoute when change permission to magento/var

Tags: magento-1.7, magento

I am following the step by step [magento installation instruction](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magento-installation-cheat-sheet)

But when I finish step 3 and try to run the site it gives me the following error

> PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function getFrontNameByRoute() on a non-object in /vagrant/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php on line 199

If I change the mangeto/var permission back to 755, the site loads perfectly but if I follow the installation process, the site says

> magento/var must be writable

Hope somebody already gone through this process to help me out here.

Thank you so much.

Comment: `var/` folder needs to be 777. Or else ... you get that error.

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer to my own question.

[Magento Installation Instruction](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magento-installation-cheat-sheet) ask you to do the following,

> chmod o+w var var/.htaccess app/etc

But actually it should be

> chmod o+w -R var var/.htaccess app/etc

The contents in the 'var' directory must be writable as well, otherwise you get this error.